# Best method for getting user analytics in .net core Web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .net core web api as my service end point for my angular application . I would like to track user activities for user analytics. Could you suggest what are the best practices to track these activities?

Answer (score 1):

I am using DotNet core2 with Angular6 and developed 2 applications in my job.
I made a service (LogService) to add a log message after each function - APIs (typically main functions).
Log table in database is (id:integer, userId:integer, msg:text or json,operation: enum or text)

and filtering data using userId.
I hope to help you more, this is my info about user activities tracking

Answer (score 1):

You can follow Audit Trail implementation from https://damienbod.com/2017/02/28/implementing-an-audit-trail-using-asp-net-core-and-elasticsearch-with-nest/

Or you can override the original ILogger in .NetCore.

Step 1: create a class that inherits ILogger then override method `public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)` . ref: https://github.com/khainx127/ezStore-microservices/blob/master/source/01.Libraries/Microservice.Core.Logging/MicroserviceLogging.cs

Step 2:Create a class inherit `ILoggerProvider` and return an instance of class in step 1. ref: https://github.com/khainx127/ezStore-microservices/blob/master/source/01.Libraries/Microservice.Core.Logging/MicroserviceLoggerProvider.cs

Step 3: register your provider in Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ...

           loggerFactory.AddProvider(new MicroserviceLoggerProvider(serviceProvider.GetService<IBusControl>(), Configuration));

            ...
        }
```

Step4: call `_logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");` in controller action

This is an idea and I think you can change what you want to write into Audit Trail